# How to assign a search range selection into a register?

Tags: search, register, range

I'd like to assign the result of search range selection into a register, instead of printing it, e.g.:

```
:/pattern1/;,/pattern2/p
```

What syntax I can use to achieve that?

Comment: you mean like using redir/execute()?

Comment: I'm not sure, could be either way, so I can print the register later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:yank` ex command:

```
:/pattern1/;/pattern2/yank a
```

`a` is the register you want to use and has a default value.

**Note:** You used `;,` in your command. It should be either `;` or `,`, not both.